# Is there any way to add dummy column in dynamic query execution in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to add dummy column in dynamic query execution in SQL Server?

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

declare @centerid int

@sql= 'Select ms.SetTitle,se.Quantity as ccp ,'' as dlp  from StockEntry_Center se
             inner join Mast_Set ms on se.SetID=ms.SetID where se.IsDeleted=''False'' and se.CenterID='+convert(nvarchar,@centerid)

exec(@sql)
```

In the above dynamic query I want to add a dummy column `'' as dlp`. But it shows an errors. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `SET @sql = 'query here'`. Show error please.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error do you get? After all, we **cannot** read your screen, nor your mind - you'll **have to tell us!**

Comment: You are trying to add a dummy column which is, in fact an empty string. Regardless of the possibility of this being the issue, it is a very, **VERY** bad practice. I would suggest you deploy `'dummy'` instead,

Comment: @FDavidov What exactly is wrong with a dummy field being an empty string?

Comment: Can't tell you that this is the issue, but I would avoid using something that could be soooooo not unique. It's a matter of guts feeling. I would not do that. If you take a look at the submitted answers, they are both setting something different from a empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because of the single quotes as gofr1 has already explained but I would also make a few other changes in your query:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @centerid int = 100

SET @sql= N' Select ms.SetTitle
                   ,se.Quantity as ccp 
                   ,'''' as dlp  
             from StockEntry_Center se
             inner join Mast_Set ms on se.SetID = ms.SetID 
             where se.IsDeleted=''False'' 
             and se.CenterID = @centerid'

Exec sp_executesql @sql
                  ,N'@centerid int'
                  ,@centerid
```

Use sp_executesql and pass the parameters as Parameters rather then concatenating it to your dynamic sql, you have only an Integer variable in this case but if you ever do this concatenation with a string variable you and exposing yourself to a possible sql-injection attack, better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'''' as dmp` or `NULL as dmp`. I bet you got errors because of quotes.

Comment: `''''` will resolve into a single quote. It should be `''''''`.

Comment: @FDavidov it should be ''' if you are concatenating with some other variable that needs to be in quotes like '''+@param+''' so it gives 'param'.

Comment: The question includes a select that reads `'Select ms.SetTitle,se.Quantity as ccp ,'' as dlp  ...`, which is converted into `Select ms.SetTitle,se.Quantity as ccp ,' as dlp ...` which is obviously an error.

Comment: @FDavidov Yes, I know that, please check `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT '''' as dmp';PRINT @sql;EXEC(@sql)
` It will give what OP wants.

Comment: got it sir @FDavidov. There was a mistake of single quotes it should     be ' ' ' '   instead of  ' '

Comment: @user6180198 that is exactly what I told in my answer and I'm not FDavidov :) I suggest you to mark M.Ali answer as accepted because it is the most relevant for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading your select (and making it easier to walk-through):

```
@sql = 'Select ms.SetTitle,se.Quantity as ccp ,
               ''                      as dlp  
          from   StockEntry_Center se
         inner join 
                 Mast_Set          ms 
         on      se.SetID = ms.SetID 

    where se.IsDeleted=''False'' 
      and se.CenterID='+convert(nvarchar,@centerid) ;
```

This converts to:

```
Select ms.SetTitle,se.Quantity as ccp ,
       '                       as dlp  
      from   StockEntry_Center se
   inner join 
             Mast_Set          ms 
     on      se.SetID = ms.SetID 

 where se.IsDeleted=''False'' 
   and se.CenterID=convert(nvarchar,@centerid) ;
```

As you can see, there is a single `'` at the left of `as dlp`.